# External html file not showing for local client side include

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, include, client-side

I have an index.html file which I am trying to add a client side include for my footer using JavaScript. However, my "footer.htm" include is not displaying, just the text is.  I am pretty sure there is an issue with my JavaScript code.  I know there is no problem with my footer.htm file. Please Help!

```js
document.write('footer.htm');
```

```html
<div id="Footer">
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="footer.js">
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.write` will literally write the string you provide to the document. It does not include files in the page. To do what you need you should use server-side includes (if available on your hosting) or AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#footer').load('footer.htm');
    });
</script>
```